# Howto write a bookmarklet that works like wget --page-requisites?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I don't understand how the getpocket.com bookmarklet works. I just know that you have to create an iframe in order to be able to download a complete webpage. The zotero.org bookmarklet is simpler, but I don't understand it as well. Thanks!

```
javascript: (function() { //getpocket.com bookmarklet
    var e = function(t, n, r, i, s) {
        var o = [8835054, 6490712, 3340024, 4585684, 4159055, 1352510, 4656739, 7999594, 1229009, 3623230];
        var i = i || 0,
            u = 0,
            n = n || [],
            r = r || 0,
            s = s || 0;
        var a = {
            'a': 97,
            'b': 98,
            'c': 99,
            'd': 100,
            'e': 101,
            'f': 102,
            'g': 103,
            'h': 104,
            'i': 105,
            'j': 106,
            'k': 107,
            'l': 108,
            'm': 109,
            'n': 110,
            'o': 111,
            'p': 112,
            'q': 113,
            'r': 114,
            's': 115,
            't': 116,
            'u': 117,
            'v': 118,
            'w': 119,
            'x': 120,
            'y': 121,
            'z': 122,
            'A': 65,
            'B': 66,
            'C': 67,
            'D': 68,
            'E': 69,
            'F': 70,
            'G': 71,
            'H': 72,
            'I': 73,
            'J': 74,
            'K': 75,
            'L': 76,
            'M': 77,
            'N': 78,
            'O': 79,
            'P': 80,
            'Q': 81,
            'R': 82,
            'S': 83,
            'T': 84,
            'U': 85,
            'V': 86,
            'W': 87,
            'X': 88,
            'Y': 89,
            'Z': 90,
            '0': 48,
            '1': 49,
            '2': 50,
            '3': 51,
            '4': 52,
            '5': 53,
            '6': 54,
            '7': 55,
            '8': 56,
            '9': 57,
            '\/': 47,
            ':': 58,
            '?': 63,
            '=': 61,
            '-': 45,
            '_': 95,
            '&': 38,
            '$': 36,
            '!': 33,
            '.': 46
        };
        if (!s || s == 0) {
            t = o[0] + t
        }
        for (var f = 0; f < t.length; f++) {
            var l = function(e, t) {
                return a[e[t]] ? a[e[t]] : e.charCodeAt(t)
            }(t, f);
            if (!l * 1) l = 3;
            var c = l * (o[i] + l * o[u % o.length]);
            n[r] = (n[r] ? n[r] + c : c) + s + u;
            var p = c % (50 * 1);
            if (n[p]) {
                var d = n[r];
                n[r] = n[p];
                n[p] = d
            }
            u += c;
            r = r == 50 ? 0 : r + 1;
            i = i == o.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1
        }
        if (s == 233) {
            var v = '';
            for (var f = 0; f < n.length; f++) {
                v += String.fromCharCode(n[f] % (25 * 1) + 97)
            }
            o = function() {};
            return v + '63c152b5d8'
        } else {
            return e(u + '', n, r, i, s + 1)
        }
    };
    var t = document,
        n = t.location.href,
        r = t.title;
    var i = e(n);
    var s = t.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'https://getpocket.com/b/r4.js?h=' + i + '&u=' + encodeURIComponent(n) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(r);
    e = i = function() {};
    var o = t.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || t.documentElement;
    o.appendChild(s)
})()
```

Comment: I know that in chrome you can download complete pages as mhtml files. But that's not what I want to do.

Comment: the "wget" part is done server-side, you can see there is a single call to their API with the page url & title (since you're logged to their domain, they can match your call to your account). No page retrieve is done from the browser.

Comment: @topheman But how can they access a page which is only available through VPN (me being logged in)?

Comment: If you want to access your page accross different computers/devices (like getpocket), make the same kind of of backend as them with an API that could also take html from `document.body.innerHTML` in params in the payload.